# Create persistent lock dynamically in Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my scripted pipeline I want to create a lock that will persists in the global Jenkins configuration, after the pipeline has finished. I tried the following to no avail.

```
import org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager as LRM
lrm = LRM.get()
lrm.createResource("my_lock")
lrm.save()
```

The lockable resource is ephemeral: It is created and can be used, but it does not persist.
I am on Jenkins 2.226 running the Lockable Resources plugin 2.7.

Comment: For completeness sake, let me add that I am aware of the ephemeral nature of the locks that are created on demand through lock("new_lock").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
import org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager as LRM
lrm = LRM.get()
lrm.createResource("my_lock")
// Get lockable resource by name
def lockableResource = lrm.fromName("my_lock")
// Make resource permanent (Resources are ephemeral by default)
lockableResource.setEphemeral(false)
lrm.save()
```

Lockable resources are ephemeral by default. To override it, use method `setEphemeral(boolean)`.